# AWS SSO fingerprint not working on Safari or Firefox

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, safari, aws-sso

I have configured AWS SSO WebAuthn using fingerprint scanner on my Macbook. It saves me a ton of time not having to copy the authenticator code. Works seamlessly for Chrome.
However, I need to have it working on Safari or Firefox too as I want to have multiple accounts open at once.
When I open SSO link in Safari and Firefox, it gets stuck here.
[image: Safari]

Couldn't find any solutions for this. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem. It works like a charm in Chrome but not in Safari. There are errors in the web console: "User gesture is not detected. To use the WebAuthn API, call 'navigator.credentials.create' within user activated events." and below "The request has been cancelled by the user". Have you found the cause or a workaround?

Comment: @Spi I haven't found the solution sadly. Hopefully someone comes up with an answer

Answer (score 0):

I used to face the similar challenge with Safari on MacBookPro M1. However, the issue seem to have disappeared. The caveat is that you should register the fingerprint scanner as SSO's MFA device from Safari again. Currently, I have registered the same fingerprint scanner as SSO's MFA device twice, one each for Safari and Chrome.